# Fake subdomain for different users while still browsing same folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'd like to create fake subdomains for different users for more vanity, and to make the user (in this case a company) feel they are in a more isolated environment.

For the sake of maintainability, it's important for me that all users still browse the same files, to avoid having to update files for every single user that exists when updating the code.

My website has one public part at root, let's say `www.example.com`. I'd like to be able to fake the following kind of subdomains:

```
user1.example.com
```

The true URL would be `www.example.com/member/?user=user1`. I'd like for the folder structure to follow the same pattern. `www.example.com/member/settings/?user=user1` would appear as `user1.example.com/settings/` and so on.

I assume this would best be achieved with `.htaccess`, no?.
What is the proper `.htaccess` code for this?

Thank you!

Comment: When you ask for .htaccess that means you are on a provider webspace and have no access to the whole webserver configuration?

Comment: In fact, I'm on a VPS, with an IP of my own and access to WHM. If there's a better way, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was super easy to solve! It wasn't solved the way I first expected though, using .htaccess. I solved it with something called wildcard subdomain.

When you register a new subdomain, enter * in the domain prefix, such as *.example.com. A folder for the wildcard subdomain will be created on your server, such as *_wildcard_.example.com*. Whenever you access *site1.example.com*, *fakesub.example.com* etc, the browser of the visitor will read the files in the *wildcard*.example.com folder.

The beauty of it all is that if I create a certain subdomain that I want to use, for example *forum.example.com*, this real subdomain will have priority over the wildcard subdomain, and files will be fetched from the folder for this subdomain, as opposed to from the wildcard subdomain folder.

I use PHP and need to know the subdomain to fetch the appropriate database for the current user. To do this, I use the following code:

```
$subdomain = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0]
```

With a wildcard SSL cert I have all of these subdomains secure.

Answer (score 2):

based on the information you've provided here's a bit of .htaccess not tested but might do the job.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$2? [R=302,L]
```

Once you find it working fine, replace 302 to 301

Note: It's important to note that you'll need to add a subdomain wildcard

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't redirect unfortunately. I added a wildcard subdomain, but whenever I add any characters before .example.com, it just shows the index.html file I placed in the subdomain folder. I placed the .htaccess file both in www.example.com root, and in _wildcard_.example.com root as well. Why doesn't the .htaccess file have effect?